# Spring Batch @ComponentScan does not scan third-part packages (org, ...)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to run a Spring Batch job via CommandJobLineRunner.

I am using a command like this:

```
$ java -cp "classes;dependency-jars/*" org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner com.iberdrola.digital.cats.batch.process.anony.config.AnonymizerFTPConfig dbAnonymizerI
```

*AnonymizerFTPConfig* is my @ConfigurationClass, where I have the @ComponentScan annotation to load basePackages. If I use it, I do not have any problem with autowiring classes from another packages from my project. However @Autowiring does not work for org.* packages like those which contain SftpSession or JdbcTemplate.

My annotation is in the aforementioned configuration class:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.iberdrola.digital.cats.batch.process.anonymizer.tasklet", "org.springframework.jdbc.core", "org.springframework.integration.sftp.session"})
```

So, why I am having problems when autowiring third part classes in CommandJobLineRunner? If I run the Spring Batch Application via Spring Boot in Eclipse I do not have those problems.

Thank you very much in advance.

All the best,
Ángel Manuel.

Comment: Those packages do not contain beans nor configuration so nothing will be detected. You need your own configuration class for this.

Comment: I guess you refer to org.* packages. Well, but I need to autowire classes like SftpSession, which cannot be created with a constructor. Besides, I still have problems to understand why I do not have problems with @autowired when running everything from Spring Boot console in Eclipse, just via CommandJobLineRunner.

Comment: The fact that you need to autowire them doesn't automatically make it that they are detected as beans. You need a configuration class that creates an `SftpSession` there is no way it can be automatically created as it requires configuration etc. Why it works locally is probably because you have additinal configuration, how are you createing the executable jar? O wait you are using Spring Batch instead of Sprig Boot yu should be using the latter to run the jar (which is proabbly as well what you do in your IDE).

Comment: I understand. Maybe I need to point to the .jar file. I am running the aforementioned command from the target folder of the project. The command and instructions are in the question. Could you revise it?

Comment: Inside my target folder, I have those elements: classes/
coverage-reports/
dependency-jars/
digitkpi.jar
digitkpi.jar.original
generated-sources/
generated-test-sources/
maven-archiver/
maven-status/
site/
surefire-reports/
test-classes/

Comment: As stated in your IDE you are running the Spring Boot application, whereas you totally bypass Spring Boot on the commandline. 2 different modes of running. Instead you need to run the jar directly instead of through spring batch and use the Spring Boot support to launch the job you want.

Comment: **java -jar digitkpi.jar org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner com.iberdrola.digital.cats.batch.process.anony.config.AnonymizerFTPConfig dbAnonymizerI** also fails. However, could you clarify about the Spring Boot support? I tried to install the Spring Boot CLI but it doesn't work for Batch. I want to be able to run a batch from terminal.

Comment: You dont need the cli. Just launch the jar `java -jar your.jar`. No batch runner etc. you are doing the same in your IDE by launching the `main` from your `@SpringBootApplication` annotation class. You are using two totally different execution models and wonder why they behave differently.

Comment: So, I guess that for those autowired problems I cannot use the CommandJobLineRunner, but that I must run the jar normally.

Comment: That is the whole point of using Spring Boot. Or also use the `CommandLineJobRunner` in your IDE to have the same issues so you can solve it. But as stated you are using Spring Boot then utilize it to your advantage.

Comment: I want to use CommandLineJobRunner  via terminal because I want to encapsulate the commands in a .sh script to be scheduled via CTRL+M

Comment: No you don't want that, you still want to use Spring Boot. What makes you think you cannot pass the commands to Spring Boot. You use the same in your IDE.

Comment: So, I will run java -jar solution.jar (the JAR refers to spring boot program). Thanks a lot for your attention.